Can I tie together a 110 from one serial bus to 110 coming from another cereal bus to make a single 220 hotwire?
I have a breaker box that is located outside on a power pole in the driveway at a location where I have a small workshop. I need to have a outlet in my shop that will supply 220 volts that I can run various small handheld tools from. In my breaker box there's two hot buses the ground and neutral. Is it okay to bring a hot wire off of each bus and tie them together to make a single wire 220 hot? Then use the one neutral and one ground? Am I correct in believing that
Because they are out of phase from each other that day will match together? Or will there be trouble?

Are you being serious right now? Maybe I have used the wrong term but I know that you understand what I'm talking about.

ok, sorry about the breakfast comment ... even serial bus does not make sense ... do you mean phase?

Well I'm not positive I'm using the right terminology so I'll try and explain it the best I can. There is two lateral bars inside my breaker box that are hot each breaker in the line of breakers is offset one hooks to one bar then the next hooks to the other bar so I'm assuming that those are both hot but out of face from each other is that correct? If I'm correct is it possible to tie both of those together to make a 220 hot?

A "serial bus" is a type of data connection, not a power connection. Just call it a circuit.

Most handheld power tools use 120 volts.  240 volts are usually left to larger tools.  Unless in Europe.  For 240 volts you want to use a double breaker instead of two single breakers, so both hots are turned off together.  You never connect two hots together.

As you say, they're out of phase. That means that you get 120V from each one to ground and 240V from one to the other. Don't connect them together; 240V won't like that.

DONT DO THAT.
Do not twist the two Hot/phase wires together. Do not connect the buses together. You will create a dead short. And blow a fuse. And maybe burn something. This is not water plumbing where you can combine smaller pipes into larger one.
You need to have a correct 220V outlet that will require either 3 or 4 wires. Each of the Hot/phase wires goes to separate terminal.
Is the box on power pole after a power meter? Does it have cutoff switch? "Power Pole" makes me think it is something you should not be messing with.
I recommend you hire someone licensed to do the work.

OP also needs a proper "220" double breaker with common trip to feed the two hot/phase wires. OP, please don't wire the power wires directly to the bus bars! Go through a double circuit breaker that is officially compatible with your existing panel.
